# How to navigate a soft link from netrw?

Tags: neovim, netrw

I just want to navigate the contents of a soft link that points to a directory using netrw.

How can I navigate into it?

My OS is: Arch Linux and
I use: Zsh

Answer (score 0):

If the `file_to_path` feature is present in your version of Vim (use the Vim command `:version` to verify that then it should work out of the box (using the `:Explore` command or the `gf` key command).

Here is a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/684234/329318) to a similar question in SE.

Remark: Tested on Ubuntu + Vim 9.1 / Neovim 0.9.5

Comment: thanks for your help.  I have Neovim 0.9.5 but it looks it doesn't have that feature enabled.  I tried both suggested commands and it does nothing.  I used a package manager to install it.  Maybe I'll need to compile and install it myself.

Comment: Indeed the easiest to get all the feature is to compile Neovim yourself. This is what I have done on Ubuntu and the feature came by default.

Comment: I cloned the neovim repository from github and compiled it as Release and with Debugging information and it didn't included the feature.  How can I configure the compilation to enable it?

Comment: I never did it myself but I believe you have to run the `./configure` script with the following arguments `./configure --with-features=file_to_path` or mabye  `./configure --with-features=huge`. Then run `./make` normally.

Comment: There's no `configure` script.